# Serializing a DataTable for use in RAZOR

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that uses RAZOR. My controller action loads data into a DataTable (I inherited the code). I need to render that data as JSON in my View. I attempted to use the approach recommended to me here: [Writing JSON via MVC and RAZOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281647/writing-json-via-mvc-and-razor).

I believe the DataTable is causing my problems though. At the same time, I'm not sure what to do. How do I get certain columns from the DataRow elements rendered as JSON in my view? Currently, I have the following in my controller action:

```
DataTable results = GetFromDatabase();
ViewBag.Results = results;
```

Then, in my view I have:

```
@{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var resultsJson = serializer.Serialize(Enumerable.Select(ViewBag.Results, result => new { id = result["ID"], name = result["Name"] }));
    Html.Raw(resultsJson);
}
```

When I attempt this, I receive an error that says:
*Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type*

I'm not sure how to remedy this problem.

Comment: Check [HERE](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/198/Cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operation)

Comment: Firstly, I'd recommend doing the serialization earlier on in the process, either in the controller code or the model, and having the controller pass a JSON object to the view.

Comment: Also, please provide a bit of context as to what you wish to show on the view. I'm imagining that the data should be objectified, and then you would serialize those objects rather than a `DataTable` with all its overhead and such.