# RAZOR Javascript coding assistance

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following JS code that I use to create an object:

```
var TransactionData = {
    orderId: '@Model.Order.SalesOrderNumber.SelfOrDefault().FullOrderNuber',
    curreny: "USD",
    total: '@Model.Order.TotalSalesPrice',
    items: [
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model.Order.LineItems)
            {
                sku: item.ProductId,
                quantity: item.Quantity,
                price: item.AdjustedUnitPrice
            }
    }]   
}
```

I need to loop through the LineItems in my Model to get the sku, quantity and price.  There are 1 to x items that need to be created.  Using the code above I get the error "; expected" after the comma in the sku:, quantity: and price: lines.  Ultimately I am trying to get the following in the items:

```
{
  "price" : "140", 
  "quantity" : "1",
  "sku" : "156278"
},
{
  "price" : "12.69", 
  "quantity" : "3",
  "sku" : "908736" 
}
```

I think I am almost there I just need to fix this error.  Any suggestions?  I am rusty on JS on RAZOR so please bear with me.

Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing server-side and client-side code.  The error is happening because you have JavaScript code in your C#.

Comment: I would create TransactionData  in my controller, pass it to the view as viewbag, use json.encode and you will get the object as json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being interpreted entirely as server-side code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Order.LineItems)
{
    sku: item.ProductId,
    quantity: item.Quantity,
    price: item.AdjustedUnitPrice
}
```

Which, of course, is a syntax error because those three lines are not valid C#.  Instead, you want to treat those as client-side code with some server-side values emitted to the output.  Something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Order.LineItems)
{
    <text>
    {
        sku: @item.ProductId,
        quantity: @item.Quantity,
        price: @item.AdjustedUnitPrice
    },
    </text>
}
```

Though, the more manual effort that you put into building your JavaScript structures in Razor code, the more you begin to justify just serializing the structures instead.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281647/writing-json-via-mvc-and-razor) is a good place to start with that.  You can use any serializer you like, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way to manipulate javascript code within Razor is to encapsulate it with `<text>` tags.

See this post:
[Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

Hope it solves your syntax errors!

Comment: As the users commented above, I don't think the optimal way to manipulate your data is by using Razor to manipulate javascript, but if you're going to do it anyway, the <text> tag should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally ended up with:

```
var items = [  
    @foreach (var item in Model.Order.LineItems)
        {
            <text>
                {
                    sku: '@item.Product.SKU',
                    quantity: '@item.Quantity',
                    price: '@item.AdjustedUnitPrice',
                    name: '@item.Product.Description.Name'
                },
            </text>
        }
];
```

This creates the array of items and then use:

```
items: items
```

to set the array and it works.

Thanks all.